# Is there a way to hasten recovery from sleep inertia?

Tags: performance, sleep

> Sleep inertia is a transitional state of lowered arousal occurring immediately after awakening from sleep and producing a temporary decrement in subsequent performance. (1)

There is study demonstrating what increases sleep inertia

> One of the most critical factors is the sleep stage prior to awakening.  Abrupt awakening during a slow wave sleep (SWS) episode produces more sleep inertia than awakening in stage 1 or 2, REM sleep being intermediate. Therefore, prior sleep deprivation usually enhances sleep inertia since it increases SWS. (1)

**I am interested in what can be done to alleviate sleep inertia (rather than reducing the causation).**

> Finally, sleep disorders represent risk factors which deserve new insight in treatment strategies to counteract the adverse effects of sleep inertia. (1)

(1) [Sleep inertia.](http://www.smrv-journal.com/article/S1087-0792%2800%2990098-4/abstract)
Tassi P, Muzet A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a completely scientific answer, but a few suggestions that I'd make based on a general understanding of the sleep literature:

- Increase the amount of sleep you are getting in general and thereby reduce sleep debt
- Increase the amount of sleep you are getting on the immediately preceding night (i.e., both these points are that its easier to wake up when you are less sleep deprived)
- Permit morning light to enter your room (to trigger various arousal responses)
- Maintain a regular sleep pattern to ensure that your various circadian rhythms are aligned (i.e., sleep with temperature with arousal, etc.)
- Set a mental alarm clock the night before regarding when you want to wake up
- Have a consistent morning routine to minimise the need for executive control after waking.

Comment: I know you haven't cited any studies, but all the points you make are well established within research on sleep. You are also a professional in the field of [cogsci.se] (although it is broad), but for that I respect your answers and approaches